# PlanetScale : Import / Export to CSV in MySQL Shell requires Access to Servers Filesystem

Tags: mysql, database, shell, export-to-csv

If I want to do an **export to csv** or an **import from csv**, I will need access to the filesystem from within my MySQL Database Shell.

e.g.

```
SELECT id, filename
FROM attachments
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/results.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I am using PlanetScale right now, and i don't know how or where I can get access to the servers filesystem in order to import or export data from within the mysql shell.

Comment: See FILE privilege and secure_file_priv option variable value.

Answer (score 0):

See https://vitess.io/docs/14.0/reference/compatibility/mysql-compatibility/

> The `SELECT ... INTO` form of `SELECT` in MySQL enables a query result to
> be stored in variables or written to a file. Vitess supports `SELECT`
> `... INTO DUMPFILE` and `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` constructs for unsharded
> keyspaces but does not support storing results in variable. Moreover,
> the position of `INTO` must be towards the end of the query and not in
> the middle. An example of a correct query is as follows:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM <tableName> INTO OUTFILE 'x.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
> ```
>
> For sharded keyspaces this statement can still be used **but only after
> specifying the exact shard with a USE Statement.**

(emphasis mine)

So you must know which server to use, because it's required that you specify the shard.

Once you specify the shard, you can export onto the filesystem of that shard. Presumably you know which server each of your shards are running on. That's up to you, I can't help you with that.

And obviously if you're using a managed database server like RDS for your shards, the cloud vendor doesn't allow ssh to the server to access the files, so `SELECT ... INTO` isn't possible regardless of using Planetscale.

Comment: not sure if this is an answer. what does this imply?

Comment: @Pencilcheck: I've edited to clarify. If you still have a problem with this answer, please be more specific.